# How to escape colon in the attribute key with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf, template-engine

I want to generate the following entry in .xml file with Thymeleaf

`<postalCode xsi:type="extPL:adxp.postalCode"> </postalCode>`

to do so, I have the following template:

`<postalCode th:attr="xsi:type='extPL:adxp.postalCode' </postalCode>`

but the phrase `xsi:type` contains colon which breaks the syntax of the expression. How can I escape the colon to make it work?
I tried various approaches with substituting `&#58;` for colon or `&quot;` for `'`, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: It looks like you forgott a `"` in your template right before `</postalCode>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use single quotes `'` to mask the colon like so

```
<postalCode th:attr="'xsi:type'='extPL:adxp.postalCode' </postalCode>
```

or the whole attribute argument

```
<postalCode th:attr="'xsi:type=extPL:adxp.postalCode'" </postalCode>
```

Comment: The first approach works! I was sure I even tested it, but maybe I discarded it when IDE gave me warnings about synthax... Thank you!